# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una variable creada en vista a un controlador en Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Quiero enviar una variable $diferencia->d creada en la vista blade en php al controlador y del controlador enviarla a otra vista.

En la vista donde creo la variable tengo de la siguiente forma

```
              <?php
                  $fecha = new DateTime ($multa->fecha_notificacion);
                  $fechahoy = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
                  $diferencia = $fecha->diff($fechahoy);
              ?>
              @if ($diferencia->y == 0 && $diferencia->m == 0 && $diferencia->d <="15" || $diferencia >="11")
                <div class="stats">
                    <i class="material-icons text-success">visibility</i>
                    <a href="{{route('contratos.multas.index', [$multa->contrato->id,$diferencia->d])}}">Ver multa</a>
                </div>
              @endif
            @endforeach
```

y en el controlador tengo lo siguiente

```
public function index(Contrato $contratos, Request $request)
    {
        return view('multas.index',compact('contratos'),['contratos'=>Contrato::all(),'multas'=>Multas::all()]);
    }
```

Desde el controlador quiero enviar la variable $diferencia->d a otra vista.

En web.php tengo la siguiente ruta

```
Route::resource('contratos.multas', App\Http\Controllers\MultasController::class);
```

Comment: Lo que quiero es ver que en el controlador llegue el valor de la variable, y así enviar ese mismo valor a otra vista.

Comment: lo tendrías que pasar a través de un <Form> ya sea por post o get, de esa forma lo capturas en la otra vista

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, lo que tienes que hacer es crear un input type="hidden" y en el value="" colocas el valor de lo que quieres recibir en el request de ese controlador.

Ejemplo:

```
<form action="{{ route('nombre.ruta') }}" method="POST" role="form" id="form_paso1" name="form_paso1">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <input type="hidden" name="diferencia" id="diferencia" value="{{ $diferencia->d}}" />
</form>
```

De esa manera, lograrás recibirlo en el controlador. Esto lo puedes usar cuando requieres un parámetro, o simplemente verificar con ese valor como una especie de bandera.

Una vez que lo recibas en ese request del controlador, lo usas como parámetro cuando quieras enviar la vista. O simplemente la envías como un valor en el método compact.

Ejemplo con compact:

```
return view('nombre.ruta', compact('diferencia'));
```

Ejemplo en forma de parámetro:

```
return view("nombre.ruta", ["diferencia" => $diferencia]);
```

Espero haberte ayudado.